# MySQL database with many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I want to create some number of tables (lets say as sub tables) and make all sub tables to point to one main table. If i query with main table I should be able get details from all sub tables together or even from individual subtable table details. I am using python interface for querying.

This is my requirement. Kindly suggest me some ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: mysql ?? sqlserver ?? different DB altogether

Comment: Depends on kind of data stored in those tables. If you are looking for query then you can define views.

Comment: mysql @AmeyaDeshpande

Comment: how to make sub tables point to main table ? @Vijay

Comment: Learn about `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why are you not using mySQL on terminal to use queries.Why are you using python?

So as per your requirement let us take an example.Let us create a database book_info where there are 4 tables-

1. tbl_books
2. tbl_author
3. tbl_book_reviews
4. tbl_book_sales

Let **tbl_book** be the main table.
It will contain-

**| book_id | book_title | publication | price | ISBN  |**

**tbl_author** will contain-

**| author_id | first_name | last_name | DOB  | address | email_id   |**

**tbl_book_reviews** will contain-

**| review_id | book_id | | author_id | Review |**

And finally **tbl_book_sales** will contain-

**| book_sale_id | book_id | years | city  | quantity**

So you can get data from all the tables using [Joins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm) as book_id is used as a foreign key in every table.
Try creating tables and executing queries on terminal or mysql Workbench.

Comment: thank you. Got something which i should learn deep to get my requirement.

Comment: You are Welcome